# API to sign up for google Apps

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api

I have been working on a problem where I have some domain list and I have to register those domains with Google Apps. I am unable to figure out any API provided by google for that purpose.
Is there any API that allows me to signup for Google Apps ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's available only via web interface being an action done very rarely. Your use case is not really common.